# Relationships in Model Ruby on Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, sybase

I have a View called `View_CrossReference` in Sybase. I want to create Model for this view.
This table has a column called `Answer`.

I have an another table and model called `SurveyXref`. In this table i have a column
called `Answer_No`.

I want to create a relationship between these models and get the data from `Answer` column from `View_CrossReference` and display into my grid in `SurveyXref` page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN view_crossreference model

> has_one :survey_xrefs, :primary_key => :answer, :foreign_key =>
>   :answer_no

In survey_xrefs model

> belongs_to :view_crossreference, :primary_key => :answer ,
>   :foreign_key => :answer_no

now simply in controller u can access

> v.view_crossreference.answer

Comment: shall i keep this model view_crossreference into the same folder of survey_xref? or to create a View folder and save it?

Comment: modela are placed in same folders

Comment: is it possible to create a relationship without having column in my model? I want to some datas from another model. But I dont have any foreign key to get the data from that model.

Answer (score 0):

Without "Model", means you have created table via stand alone migration.
Could you please show me your code for better understanding?

Comment: Hi, Thanks. First thing is I want to create a model for this table View_CrossReference. So, Where do i want to create a model? Into the View folder or what?

Comment: follow these urls. It may help you with core concept.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html